# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined i am trying to update rawmaterial fields using this controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

i am trying to update fields using this

```
exports.updateRawmaterial = (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.rawmaterial._id)
    Rawmaterial.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.rawmaterial._id }, { $set: req.body }, { new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
        (err, updatedRawmaterial) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "NOT able to update rawmaterial"
                });
            }
            return res.json(updatedRawmaterial);
        })
}
```

please help me

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(req.rawmaterial._id)` ?

Comment: @IsmailElMoudni i am getting undefind  ```_id```

Comment: can get the output of `console.log(req.rawmaterial);` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@laxman

1. please check that you are using

   `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

As a Middleware. include this middleware to convert and recognize the incoming Request Object as a JSON Object.

2. next thing please check you must do
   `req.body.rawmaterial._id` if you are doing a post request from somewhere.
3. check if while doing the request the data is being sent or not.

This 3 steps will surely resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Dhruv Barot

If still not resolved then pls comment.

Comment: ahhh yes bro but i have included body parser already but its showing deprecated

Comment: i am trying to do a put request here,  and its saying undefined

Answer (score -1):

the problem was in routes i was not calling my routes correctly there was some spelling mistake in my route

```
router.put("/rawmaterial/:rawmaterialId/:userId", updateRawmaterial);
```

i had spell mistake in `:rawmaterialId`